# FullPage.js Scrollable Container - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, scrollbar, fullpage.js

**Desired Result and Problem**

I am using fullPage.js for page scrolling for the sections on my website. The portfolio is not fitting in one "page section" - and I need it to be inside a scrollable section (without moving to another page section).   I would like the user to be able to scroll within the "portfolio container" to scroll down to view other companies, but not scroll past the companies page.

**What I have Tried**

To achieve this I have inserted this into my added js code which is supposed to enable scrollbars for the section, and also "reset" the scrollbars thereafter.

```
var movedo_grve_fullpage_data = {"scrollOverflow": "true"};
var movedo_grve_fullpage_data = {"scrollOverflowReset": "true"};
```

[Link To Page](https://neue.run-time.co.za/)

However instead of scrolling within the "portfolio grid" it is scrolling into a new "page" and when scrolling back - a white block is left below the grid

Comment: It would help you can provide an isolated reproduction of your issue instead of a link to your page. See [this example using ScrollOverflow](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/scrollOverflow.html) too.